# In Python, run each row in a csv through tests and output a new csv showing which test each row failed

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning, pseudocode

In python, I would like to run a csv through test cases checking for data anomalies while keep track of each test it fails.

This is my first big project in Python, though I have Python experience and can do basic one-liners using pandas like `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['UniqueID'])`, I just am not sure what the right direction would be.

- Data Example:

| MnLast | MnFist | MnDead? | MnInactive? | SpLast | SpFirst | SPInactive? | SpDead? | Addee | Sal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | No | No | Doe | Jane | No | No | Mr. John Doe | Mr. John |

> Main(Mn) record isn't blank, Spouse(Sp) record isn't blank, neither record is marked deceased but **Addee** or **Sal** doesn't have '&' or 'and'. This indicates the Addressee(Addee) or Salutation(Sal) is incorrect, as Addressee or Salutation should have a variation of: "*Mr. and Mrs. John doe*"

- Pseudo code:

```
Read csv

for each row in csv

  #test case 1
  if [ {( (MNFirst AND MnLast) =! BLANK ) AND ( (SpLast AND SpFirst) =! BLANK )} AND 
  (( SpDead? AND MnDead?) =! Yes)] AND [(Addee OR Sal) Does not contains ('&' or 'and')] 
  
     output failing row to new csv tracking what case it failed

  else 

      nothing
```

- My goal

Read a csv file, run the file through several test cases(there are several). Then output a new csv, with a new column indicating each case it failed. So if my Data Example failed 3 different cases, the new column would show a number corresponding to the case it failed. The csv output would show the following:

| CaseFailed | MnLast | MnFist | MnDead? | MnInactive? | SpLast | SpFirst | SPInactive? | SpDead? | Addee | Sal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, 5, 8 | Doe | john | No | No | Doe | Jane | No | No | Mr. John Doe | Mr. John |

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into the .apply() function, which lets you apply functions to selections from your df: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html  .  Then you can just pass your test cases which should be implemented as functions returning bool, numerical or categorical values and itself take the column value as parameter, and you can assign them to a new column on your df. If you use apply() you might not even have to iterate df. I would also propose to add a column for each of your test cases. This makes data much more readable. Then just write to file using df.to_csv().

Comment: When I'm passing my test case through .apply(), the test case would be a lambda function?

Comment: Adding a column for each case is a great idea too, thank you.

Comment: you can define it as a lambda, but as far as i know you can also implement a function and pass it as parameter without round brackets (you pass the function object, you don't call it). The column values are parameters to the function, e.g. df.apply(np.sqrt) calculates square root for each col value.

Comment: I think I'm following. a Function checking if the spouse is dead, if dead return true.  ```data[`Column_TrueOrFalse'] = data["SpDead?"].apply(FunctionCheckingIfSpouseIsDead)```

Comment: Where in this process does comparing more than one column come in?

Comment: I would have to verify with running code, but if you add axis=1, I think you can index the parameter e.g. x in your test case function, like is done here:  https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-pandas/pandas-apply-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='latin-1')

# Create array to track failed cases.
data['Failed Test']= ''
    data = data.replace(np.nan,'')
    data.insert(0, 'ID', range(0, len(data)))

# Test 1: The spouse shows a deceased date, but martial status is not marked as widowed
  testcase1 = data[((data['SRDeceasedDate'] != '') & (data['MrtlStat'] != 'Widowed'))]
    ids = testcase1.index.tolist()
    for i in ids:
      data.at[i,'Failed Test']+=', 1'

# Test 2: Spouse name information is filled in but marital status shows single. 
 df = data[((data['SRLastName'] != '') | (data['SRFirstName'] != ''))]
    testcase2 = df[df['MrtlStat'] == 'single']
    ids = testcase2.index.tolist()
    for i in ids:
      data.at[i,'Failed Test']+=', 2'

# sort and separate  which rows have failed a test
failed = data[(data['Failed test'] != '')]
passed = data[(data['Failed test'] == '')]
failed['Failed Test'] = failed['Failed Test'].str[1:]
failed = failed[(failed['Failed Test'] != '')]

# Clean up
del failed["ID"]
del passed["ID"]

# Print results 
failed['Test Case Failed'].value_counts()
print("There was a total of",data.shape[0], "rows.", "There were" ,data.shape[0] - failed.shape[0], "rows passed and" ,failed.shape[0], "rows failed at least one test case")

# output failed rows
failed.to_csv("C:/Users/Output/failed.csv", index=False,) 

# output passed rows
passed.to_csv("C:/Users/Output/passed.csv", index=False,)
```